# Windows command for cutting columns from a text

Tags: windows, command-line, data-manipulation, cut

The following content is stored in a file:

```
chrome.exe                   512 Console                 0     73,780 K
chrome.exe                   800 Console                 0     11,052 K
chrome.exe                  1488 Console                 0     92,720 K
chrome.exe                  1600 Console                 0     32,344 K
chrome.exe                  2240 Console                 0     35,132 K
chrome.exe                  2360 Console                 0     21,276 K
chrome.exe                  3524 Console                 0     66,732 K
chrome.exe                  3924 Console                 0     23,524 K
```

Is there a way to extract the 5th column with the Windows command line?

Something like the UNIX `cut` command.

Answer (score 8):

Use double `%` in variable

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%i in (file.txt) DO echo %%i
```

Comment: Long time to pump up this thread, after ran like as your code, I got on my Windows 10: %%i was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 6):

If you're familiar with the GNU cut utility, you might be better off using the Win32 port:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: Similarly I found it easy to use use [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) which already has many unix commands installed.

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF

for /F "tokens=2-4" %%a in (%1) DO ( echo %%a %%b %%c )
```

took me a long time to find out that `%%a %%b %%c .... [%%z]` refer to subsequent colums in a text file.
So this example will extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column (word) from a textfile (%1).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use mobaxterm (https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) a ssh client, and open a local terminal. It contain unix comands like cut, grap, wc ,etc

Answer (score -3):

If you had perl installed:

```
perl.exe -na  -e "print qq{$F[4]\n}" < myfile.txt
```

Comment: If you had... isn't helpful. I'm sure poster could write code in any language to do it but that's not the question being asked.