# Recursively browsing through directory structure in Python

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse-juno

This is the code I have written:
`import os

    s=""

    pr=""

    x=""

    i=0

    for (p,d,f) in os.walk('d:\\12'):

        i+=1

        if i <= 3:

            pr=str(p)

            s=str(d)

            s=s.strip("[]")

            e=(len(s.strip("\'\'")))

            #print(s,e)

    x=str(f).strip("[]")

    y=pr+"\\"+x.strip("\'\'")

    print(y)`

This is it's output:
**d:\12\bvzcasdas\14\hello.txt**
What I want as the result is the **drive letter & the immediate sub-directory** (i.e 12) should be skipped in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut command to get output. If i get question right this should work:

```
echo "D:\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\hello.txt" | cut -d "\" -f 4-
```

This will cut the input with delimiter "\" and print from 4th column to last column.
Output will be:

```
3\4\5\6\7\8\hello.txt
```

EDIT: (After new contains in question )

You can add following line:
     os.system("echo %s | cut -d '\' -f 3- "%y);

just adjust column value to set from where to start displaying.

Comment: Thanks... but the one I have given above is just an example... The code has to be independent of the file names...

Comment: You can use any thing over there
Take path in any variable and echo $variable to echo path.
Then cut for column number

Comment: Thanks again... But i'm getting

Comment: 'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What do i have to import to use the cut command in Eclipse...? with PyDev plugin

Comment: I don't have much idea about eclipse or on windows itself.
may be (not sure) this will help to use cut (or similler command) on windows "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441827/windows-command-for-cutting-columns-from-a-text"

Comment: if it is the solution you want then accept it as correct so it may help others